# How to convert date for the first timezone to the second?

Tags: java, android

There is the following info:

- date ("2013-08-30 07:05:25")
- timezone ("Europe/Moscow")

My app gets this info from some server, and I need to convert this date/time to current user's timezone. I know that I should use DateFormat and TimeZone APIs, but I don't understand how. Please, give me a piece of advice or some code. Thanks.

Comment: If you can include a new library, I highly recommend looking into joda-time it's a great library for date time manipulation. http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ Example http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Changing_TimeZone

Comment: see my answer, it will work for your time zone

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work for you & refer this stack question for [timezones-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694885/timezones-in-java) :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));
cal.setTime(new Date());

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");

Date resultdate = new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));

System.out.println("String date:"+sdf.format(resultdate));
try {
    System.out.println("Date:"+sdf2.parse(sdf.format(resultdate)));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
String date:2013-08-31 06:25:54 PM
Date:Sat Aug 31 18:25:54 IST 2013
```