# Date format conversion error

Tags: java, date

I am facing the problem while converting the date:

Current format is:`Thu Sep 05 12:07:46 IST 2013(dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy)`

I need to convert in to:`09/04/2013 11:38 PM PDT(mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm a zzz)`

But i am not able to convert.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Did you even try using or going through SimpleDateFormatter?!

Comment: This has been asked a lot just search StackOverflow , to start with take a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: refer to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469507/how-can-i-change-the-date-format-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SimpleDateFormatter`. You have to tell it the input/output format, you can do that based [on this description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (you can also find a few common examples there).

The code will be something like this:

```
try {
    String input = "Thu Sep 05 12:07:46 IST 2013";
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("I leave this to you :-)))");
    System.out.println(formatter.parse(input));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
   try {
          DateFormat dffrom = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
          DateFormat dfto = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a zzz");  
          Date date = dffrom.parse("Thu Sep 05 12:07:46 IST 2013");     
          String s = dfto.format(date);
          System.out.println(s);
   } catch (ParseException e) {

   }
```

OutPut

09/05/2013 00:07:46 AM IST

**update**

```
   try {
        DateFormat dffrom = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
        DateFormat dfto = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a zzz");
        TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
        dfto.setTimeZone(zone);
        Date date = dffrom.parse("Thu Sep 05 12:07:46 IST 2013");       
        String s = dfto.format(date);
        System.out.println(s);
   } catch (ParseException e) {

   }
```

output

09/04/2013 11:37:46 AM PDT

Comment: Which is not what OP wants. Also code only answer is not really helpful. Care to explain it, specially when your answer is not what is required.

Comment: Can u explain me.. what i did wrong and what he is expecting?..

Comment: TimeZone issue. OP wants it in `PDT`, timezone ID for that is `"America/Los_Angeles"`, or `"PST8PDT"`. Apart from that, there is no explanation at all.

Comment: My understanding is he has date with following formate Sep 05 12:07:46 IST 2013 and he need to convert 09/04/2013 11:38 PM PDT

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST8PDT"); // example
 // required format. Remember M is for month, m for miniute
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a zzz");
df.setTimeZone(tz);
String text = df.format(new Date());// current time
System.out.println(text);
```

Also please check this **[TimeZones in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694885/timezones-in-java)**

Answer (score 0):

You try to convert dateformat and timeZone as well, so you need to convert the timezone in your code.

```
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PDT"));
Date date = isoFormat.parse("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm a zzz");
```

this may help you.