# Java get current time in Israel

Tags: java, timezone

I am tring to get the current time in Israel in java this is my code:

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Israel");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeZone(timeZone);

DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String curTime=timeFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
```

but it is always bring me 7 hours less from the current time in Israel someone have idea how to achieve the current time in Israel?

Comment: Try using `new Date()` only.

Comment: I tried now but it is not working maybe I am not doing something good can you post code that fix my original code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TimeZones in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694885/timezones-in-java)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're setting the time zone in your *calendar*, but you should be setting it in your `DateFormat`. Additionally, you should be using `Asia/Jerusalem` as the time zone name. You don't need a `Calendar` at all - just `new Date()` gives the current instant:

```
DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
timeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Jerusalem"));
String curTime = timeFormat.format(new Date());
```

You should note that the time zone in Jerusalem is particularly hard to predict (it fluctuates a lot) so if the time zone data source that your JVM uses is out of date, it may be inaccurate.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if "Israel" is a valid timezone, try "Asia/Jerusalem", have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694885/timezones-in-java) post

Comment: "Israel" is a link to "Asia/Jerusalem", which means they're identical internally.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `Locale` along with `TimeZone` if you want to display date also along with time in your language.

```
Locale aLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("iw").setRegion("IL").build();
DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM y HH:mm", aLocale);
timeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Jerusalem"));
String curTime = timeFormat.format(new Date());
```

**Note:** This is not the answer of this question but just here if in case OP is looking further for parsing date in Israel language.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Jerusalem"));
        System.out.println(time);
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
15:06:50.207521
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/lSzyD4)

If you want the format to be restricted to `HH:mm`, a couple of ways to to do so are:

1. Truncating the `LocalTime` to `ChronoUnit.MINUTES`.
2. Using `DateTimeFormatter` with the pattern, `HH:mm`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalTime timeHourMinute = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Jerusalem"))
                                            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
        System.out.println(timeHourMinute);

        // Alternatively
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Jerusalem"));
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String strTime = dtf.format(time);
        System.out.println(strTime);
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
16:01
16:01
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/lCi1Ru)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>